# SQL - ordering table by information from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-order-by, lateral-join

Title of the question may not have been very clear - I am not really sure how to name this question, but I hope that my explanation will make my problem clearer.

I have 3 tables:

[1] **score**

| id | rating_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | UPVOTE |
| 2 | UPVOTE |
| 3 | DOWNVOTE |
| 4 | UPVOTE |
| 5 | DOWNVOTE |
| 6 | DOWNVOTE |

[2] **post_score**

| post_id | score_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |

and [3] **post**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 |
| 2 | title2 |

My **goal** is to order [3] **post** table by score.

Assume UPVOTE represents value of 1 and DOWNVOTE value of -1; In this example, post where id = 1 has 3 scores related to it, and the values of them are UPVOTE, UPVOTE, DOWNVOTE, making the "numeric score" of this post: **2**;

likewise, post where id = 2, also has 3 scores, and those values are: UPVOTE, DOWNVOTE, DOWNVOTE, making the "numeric score": **-1**;

How would I order post table by this score? In this example, if I ordered by score asc, I would expect the following result:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | title2 |
| 1 | title1 |

My attempts didn't go far, I am stuck here with this query currently, which doesn't really do anything useful yet:

```
WITH fullScoreInformation AS (
    SELECT * FROM score s
    JOIN post_score ps ON s.id = ps.score_id),
    upvotes AS (SELECT * FROM fullScoreInformation WHERE rating_type = 'UPVOTE'),
    downvotes AS (SELECT * FROM fullScoreInformation WHERE rating_type = 'DOWNVOTE')
SELECT p.id, rating_type, title FROM post p JOIN fullScoreInformation fsi on p.id = fsi.post_id
```

I am using PostgreSQL. Queries will be used in my Spring Boot application (I normally use native queries).

Perhaps this data structure is bad and I should have constructed my entities differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to order post table by score. Assume UPVOTE represents value of 1 and DOWNVOTE value of -1

One option uses a subquery to count the upvotes and downvotes of each post:

```
select p.*, s.*
from post p
cross join lateral (
    select 
        count(*) filter(where s.rating_type = 'UPVOTE'  ) as cnt_up,
        count(*) filter(where s.rating_type = 'DOWNVOTE') as cnt_down
    from post_score ps
    inner join score s on s.id = ps.score_id
    where ps.post_id = p.id
) s
order by s.cnt_up - s.cnt_down desc
```

> Perhaps this data structure is bad and I should have constructed my entities differently ?

As it stands, I don't see the need for two distinct tables `post_score` and `score`. For the data you have showed, this is a 1-1 relationship, so just one table should be sufficient, storing the post id and the rating type.

Comment: I may not understand something since your query did not work as is - I had to remove x.* at the top and change `where ps.post_id = p` to `where ps.post_id = p.id` - I'd get errors otherwise. 
With these changes, however, this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You better use a `LEFT` join, otherwise you wouldn't get posts that have no votes yet. Then aggregate to get the fitered sum of the scores. Then add these sums, apply `coalesce()` to get `0` for posts without votes and order by the result.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title
       FROM post p
            LEFT JOIN post_score ps
                      ON ps.post_id = p.id
            LEFT JOIN score s
                      ON s.id = ps.score_id
       GROUP BY p.id,
                p.title
       ORDER BY coalesce(sum(1) FILTER (WHERE rating_type = 'UPVOTE')
                         +
                         sum(-1) FILTER (WHERE rating_type = 'DOWNVOTE'),
                         0);
```

I second GMB's comment about the superfluous table.

Comment: the reason for superfluous table is because I also use same system for comments. They can have score same way post can have. My current tables: score, post_score, comment_score. Does this change anything or does the table remain superfluous?

Comment: The `score` table is superfluous, yes (unless there's more to it you didn't show). Instead of the `score_id` column in `post_score` you could just have a column that directly stores whether it was an up or down vote (or even just 1 or -1 directly). For the comments and their score that's analog.